# insertions into c++ map STL container is failing

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

Please see the following code to understand my question better.

```
class compareByValue {                                                                             
  public:                                                                                          
    bool operator()(const string* s1, const string* s2) const                                      
    {                                                                                              
      if (s1 == s2)                                                                                
        return true;                                                                               
      if ((s1==NULL) || (s2==NULL))                                                                
        return false;                                                                              
      return (0 == s1->compare(s2->c_str()));                                                      
    }                                                                                                                                                                                             
}; 

map<string*, string*, compareByValue> nodeIdToIpAddress;

for (int i = 0; i < nrec; ++i) {
  nodeIdToIpAddress[ptr1[i]] = ptr2[i];                                              
  cout << "Added " << *(ptr1[i]) << " , " << *(ptr2[i]) << endl;
}

cout << "map has " << nodeIdToIpAddress.size() << " elements!" << endl;
```

I have a map that maintains key,value pairs which are pointers to string objects. I'm sure that neither keys nor values are NULL pointers. When I run the above program (well, I skipped surrounding code to make it easier to understand), "Added ... ..." gets printed 49 times. ptr1[i], ptr2[i] are pointers to string objects and are not NULL pointers because my program doesn't segfault.

The problem I have is, when I print size of map at the end, it says map has only 1 element in it.

I would appreciate if someone can give me directions to find the fix. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: @Mark solution worked like charm for me. thanks

EDIT2: After seeing valuable feedback from @Mark and @James, I think I don't need to store pointers to strings in my map. I'm going to change my code to store strings as key/values which means I don't need custom comparator functor. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know the answer (yet), but could you replace the `compare` line with `return *s1 == *s2;` ?

Comment: I did try that option. It prints only one element.

Comment: Wow... The implementation of `compareByValue::operator()` warrants a DailyWTF post. o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison operator isn't right. As long as you can assume that no nulls are added, you can throw if you detect any:

```
bool operator()(const string* s1, const string* s2) const                                      
{                                                                                              
  if (!s1 || !s2) throw std::runtime_error("Whatever");

  return *s1 < *s2;
}
```

EDIT: I should have elaborated on the reasoning here a bit more. The comparison operation that you pass into a `std::map` (or `set` or `sort` for example) must satisfy strict weak ordering. This basically means that `x OP x` is `false`, if `x OP y` is `true` then `y OP x` is `false`, and that `x OP y`, `y OP z` implies `x OP z` (as well as other rules regarding items that can't be compared).

Your function didn't satisfy this in several ways: `if (s1 == s2)` needs to return false. `if ((s1==NULL) || (s2==NULL))` can't return false because it would imply that `null < anything` and `anything < null`. You'd have to split it up and return true for `s1` null and false for `s2` null. `return (0 == s1->compare(s2->c_str()));` is incorrect because it's a three-way result rather than a `<` relation.

Since you specified that nulls would never be inserted, the simplest resolution seemed to be to throw an exception in that case (if either was null) and thenuse the string built-in operator.

All that being said now, I would strongly consider NOT storing strings by pointer in containers unless you have actual evidence that it's a performance bottleneck. A simpler design is easier to maintain and keep correct, which tends to lead to better programs long-term.

Comment: big slap on my face. how did I forget < operator overloading. Thanks. It works like charm! :-)

Answer (score 6):

Your comparator is wrong:  `if (s1 == s2)` **must** return `false` and the comparator **must** produce a [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html).

[For what it's worth, using a pointer type as the key for a `std::map` is unusual at best.]

Comment: And also the null check is wrong, if nulls ever appeared in the container: It doesn't obey strict weak ordering.

Comment: Furthermore, what he appears to want is the default behavior, so the solution to that problem is to delete the functor entirely. But there are likely other issues…

Comment: I'm not convinced but making the change you suggested didn't make any difference.

Comment: I want to compare both pointers based on the strings values they point to. I didn't want my functor to segfault when any one of them is NULL pointer. Hence I added few checks. I'm not much concerned about them being NULL because I'm sure they are not going to be NULL.

Comment: @Srikanth: You missed the point. The facts James stated _must be followed_. It's required. Your functor did not follow the requirements of a Standard Container comparator, which containers **assume are met**, and you invoked Undefined Behaviour every time you used it. Mark's answer took you straight to a superior piece of code, but he failed to teach you what you did wrong.

Comment: @James: I guess I'm being more paranoid about copying string objects.

Comment: @James: can you please enlighten me on why pointer types are unusual as map keys? I'm trying to understand the rationale. I appreciate your comments.

Comment: @srikanth:  Except where performance is a real concern, it is preferable to copy objects around rather than using pointers to objects.  Lifetime management is often more complex when using pointers and code is less maintainable.  How are you creating the key strings?  How are you managing their lifetimes?

Comment: I agree with you. lifetime management is going to be messy. one function allocates the strings on heap and at the end of using these strings the caller de-allocates from the heap.

Comment: Further, with this more complex approach, even if you get the memory management correct, you're still probably doing just as many dynamic allocations (if not more) because you have two dynamic allocations: one for the `std::string` itself and one inside of `std::string` for its buffer. If you have a move-aware standard library (recent versions of libstdc++, Visual C++ 2010, etc.) you're going to be doing _more_ work.  Unless you have profiled this part of your code and determined that it is in fact a performance bottleneck and use of pointers does indeed benefit performance, I'd avoid pointers